# Are Branch.io Test and Live keys considered secrets?

Tags: xcode, branch.io, info.plist, secret-key, app-secret

I need to add Branch.io support to an iOS app and see Branch [requires the live and test keys to be present in my Info.plist](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#4-configure-infoplist). This file is under version control and I do not want to change that.

Are these values considered app secrets and should be kept out of version control? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strongly recommended to secure these keys instead of leaving them accessible. Even thought not much can be done with this information alone but someone can use the key to create quick links via branch api and unnecessary links could be linked to our records associated with your account. Please reach out to https://help.branch.io/ for any additional queries or concern.